# Python Quiz Game Logic Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to practice python because I'm starting yr 12 soon. I created a quiz game but when i get the question right it always says that it's wrong

```
print("Welcome to the math quiz game!")
for i in range(0,10):
    operators = ['+','-','*','/']
    import random
    num1 = random.randint(1,10)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    randop = random.choice(operators)
    question = input("What is %d %s %d: " % (num1,randop,num2))
    if randop == "+":
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif randop == "-":
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif randop == "*":
        answer = num1 * num2
    elif randop == "/":
        answer = num1 / num2
    if question == answer:
        print("\nCorrect")
    elif question != answer:
        print("Incorrect or Invalid")
```

Comment: `question` is a `string` while `answer` is not. Try converting your `question`.

Comment: Although `input` is always a string and so needs to be converted to a `float`, you're going to hit issues comparing float values; what is the correct answer for `8/3`? Even without the general floating point issues, what answer would be acceptable from the user here?

Comment: @9769953 there are multiple division operations that won't result in an `int` possible from this setup

Comment: @coder80 did you make any progress with your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a comparison in a program with `==` we must compare two variables of the same *type* (which can be devious when starting Python). `Answer` is a number, while `question` is a string which was written by the user. Thus Python recognizes the two as different and false. To avoid this you must either convert the number to a string or the string to a number so you compare two variables of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned you need to cast the return value from `input()` into an float (to cope with decimals from division):

```
question = float(input("What is %d %s %d: " % (num1,randop,num2)))
```

I don't recommend doing this as a bad input will crash the game so use input validation with a `try/except` block:

```
question = input("What is %d %s %d: " % (num1,randop,num2))
try:
    question = float(question)
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid or incorrect.')
    continue # skip the rest of the code and head straight into the next iteration in the for loop
```

Also, I don't recommend including the division option as most values will be recurring decimals which cannot be input correctly unless you check beforehand that the answer will not be recurring or if you round the answer off to, say, 2 decimal places and ask the user for a 2 d.p answer

(You could also make the 'answer' variable a string instead of making 'question' an int)

Comment: @roganjosh amended answer to `float`. There is also a note about the division and possible ways to make it work with a little bit of compromise.